# MediaRecorder crashing on stop() Invalid meta-bufIndex Android

Tags: android, video, encoding, mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder to record a video. I have a preview in a Surface, and am recording from that surface.

LogCat:

```
04-03 16:19:21.682 2780-2780/nl.demo V/LOGSPMirrorView: Stopping recorder
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-14210/? D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-14210/? D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopping
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3413/? I/MediaCodecSource: encoder (video) stopping
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3418/? E/OMX-VENC-720p: ERROR: ETBProxy: Invalid meta-bufIndex = 859877778
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3418/? E/OMX-VENC-720p: ERROR: ETBProxy() failed!
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3418/? E/OMX-VENC-720p: ERROR: send OMX_ErrorHardware to Client
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3417/? E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.mpeg4] ERROR(0x80001009)
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3417/? E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001009, internalError -2147483648)
04-03 16:19:21.682 8202-3416/? E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001009, actionCode 0, while in state 6
```

The application just freezes. No crash.

This is my code for preparing the MediaRecorder:

```
public Boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_720P);
    profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
    profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP;
    profile.videoFrameHeight = 480;
    profile.videoFrameWidth = 720;
    profile.videoBitRate = 24;
    profile.videoFrameRate = 24;
    mRecorder.setProfile(profile);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder().getSurface());
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    mRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    recorderInitialized = true;
    return true;
}
```

When I call `mRecorder.stop()`, the application freezes. In my video gallery, a 32KB file is saved. Unable to play, of course.

The reason I'm recording from the Surface (`.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)`) is that recording from the camera directly gave errors with regards to camera connection (`CameraService::connect X (pid 8202) rejected (existing client with higher priority`).

I'm looking for a solution, either for the Surface recording or for using the camera record without priority conflicts.

Thanks for your advice!